# how to Defining custom settings in Odoo

Tags: odoo

http://ludwiktrammer.github.io/odoo/custom-settings-odoo.html
in this article he did

```
class YourSettings(models.TransientModel):
_inherit = 'res.config.settings'
_name = 'your.config.settings'



company_name = fields.Char()
company_phone = fields.Char()

@api.model
def get_default_company_values(self, fields):

    company = self.env.user.company_id
    return {
        'company_name': company.name,
        'company_phone': company.phone,
    }

@api.one
def set_company_values(self):
    company = self.env.user.company_id
    company.name = self.company_name
    company.phone = self.company_phone
```

i want to make `company_name = fields.Char()    to be company_name = fields.many2one('res.partner','company name')`

but the result in employee like res.partner(9,) how to make it show the name of the company 
second 
i create custom field person height ,person weight i want to add this 2 fields to this custom settings